# Running A game problem

Tags: wine, games

When i firstly ran mafia 2 game -on wine- a black screen is shown without any other progression,
but lately the normal screen shown up ( i mean the intro of the game ), but the game stops during the intro.
Can anyone help with that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Wine is an option not a solution. you can try to install proprietary graphic driver also install directx and see if it works after that.

Comment: I am sorry but what proprietary graphic driver is ? and how can i install it ?

Comment: Simply the one you have if you have the AMD card try installing AMD proprietary graphic driver for linux! 
Open your dash type in drivers, you will find addition drivers option. Let it search if additional drivers are available then it will download them and install them!

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, but it is slow a little bit, do you have any advice ?, and also i have just cause 2 on wine but when i start it a message is shown saying "directx fatal error 2" can you help me we that also?, Thank you again and sorry for asking a lot but i am a noob :).